# What corner cases exist when relying on undocumented behaviour to determine values selected by MySQL for hidden columns in GROUP BY operations?

Tags: mysql, group-by

Under [`GROUP BY` and `HAVING` with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html), the MySQL manual documents (added emphasis):

> MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the `GROUP BY` are the same for each group. **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.**

Despite this explicit warning from the developers, some people continue to rely on undocumented behaviour to determine the value that will be selected from a hidden column.

In particular, MySQL often *appears* to select the "first" record from each group (where the notion of "first" is itself undocumented, such as the oldest record on some storage engines or according to some sort order applied to a materialised table from a subquery).  I've seen this exploited to retrieve, for example, a groupwise maximum:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY sort_col DESC
) t GROUP BY group_col
```

For completeness, the same can be accomplished in a standard and [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) fashion with a simple join:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   group_col, MAX(sort_col) sort_col
  FROM     my_table
  GROUP BY group_col
) t
```

I believe that one should never rely on undocumented behaviour because there may be unforeseen corner cases that cause that behaviour to break.  For example, in satisfying a `GROUP BY` operation with an index, MySQL sorts the results and may thereby choose an unexpected value.

What other corner cases can break this behaviour?  Or is it sufficiently reliable for production systems?

Comment: It's not reliable if the documentation states it shouldn't be relied on. It may change in future releases. This is another shining example of why MySQL is often a poor choice when compared to other RDBMS systems.

Comment: It should be used, as you say, only when the results are determinate (usually when you have a `GROUP BY table.pk`) and only then. If I remember well, there's a documented case that the very exploitation you mention (`ORDER BY` in a derived table, and then `GROUP BY` in the external query) breaks with MariaDB 5.3 optimizer's enhancements.

Comment: See this question at MariaDB Knowledgebase: [GROUP BY trick has been optimized away](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/). Notice the part that says "*The EXPLAIN plan do longer shows a subquery, as if the **inner ORDER BY has been thrown away.***"

Comment: @ypercube: Thank you, that's a useful corner case to cite here for users of MariaDB.  Hopefully there are some for pure MySQL too.

Comment: @Phil: The thing about "*it may change in future releases*" is that the argument can also be applied to documented features (and is, of course, why one should always read through change logs before considering an update and then test one's application thoroughly with new versions of any dependency prior to rollout).

Comment: (I wrote the MariaDB comment.)  I have not (yet) found a counterexample standard MySQL.  But I suspect that it might happen with the new optimizations in 5.6.7.

Comment: @eggyal: Exactly. But undocumented behaviour may change without anything specific about it in the change logs.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking the `NATURAL JOIN` example you just used

```
SELECT * FROM my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   group_col, MAX(sort_col) sort_col
  FROM     my_table
  GROUP BY group_col
) t
```

If you shift to another type of `JOIN` and impose `WHERE`, ordering can come and go without warning in spite of the ill-advised reliance on undocumented behavior of the `GROUP BY`.

For this example, I will

- use Windows 7
- use MySQL 5.5.12-log for Windows
- create some sample data
- impose a `LEFT JOIN` without a `WHERE` clause
- impose a `LEFT JOIN` with a WHERE clause

For the DB Environment

```
mysql> select version();
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.5.12-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%version_co%';
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86                          |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Using this script to generate sample data

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS eggyal;
CREATE DATABASE eggyal;
USE eggyal
CREATE TABLE groupby
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    num int,
    primary key (id)
);
INSERT INTO groupby (num) VALUES
(floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),(floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),
(floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),(floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),
(floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),(floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),
(floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),(floor(rand() * unix_timestamp()));
INSERT INTO groupby (num) SELECT num FROM groupby;
SELECT * FROM groupby;
```

and these two queries for testing the `GROUP BY` subsequent use;

```
SELECT * FROM groupby A LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT   num, MAX(id) id
    FROM     groupby
    GROUP BY num
) B USING (id);
SELECT * FROM groupby A LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT   num, MAX(id) id
    FROM     groupby
    GROUP BY num
) B USING (id) WHERE B.num IS NOT NULL;
```

Let's test the durability of the `GROUP BY`'s results;

## STEP 01 : Create the Sample Data

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS eggyal;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE eggyal;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE eggyal
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE groupby
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     num int,
    ->     primary key (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO groupby (num) VALUES
    -> (floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),(floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),
    -> (floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),(floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),
    -> (floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),(floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),
    -> (floor(rand() * unix_timestamp())),(floor(rand() * unix_timestamp()));
Query OK, 8 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO groupby (num) SELECT num FROM groupby;
Query OK, 8 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM groupby;
+----+------------+
| id | num        |
+----+------------+
|  1 |  269529129 |
|  2 |  387090406 |
|  3 | 1126864683 |
|  4 |  411160755 |
|  5 |   29173595 |
|  6 |  266349579 |
|  7 | 1244227156 |
|  8 |    6231766 |
|  9 |  269529129 |
| 10 |  387090406 |
| 11 | 1126864683 |
| 12 |  411160755 |
| 13 |   29173595 |
| 14 |  266349579 |
| 15 | 1244227156 |
| 16 |    6231766 |
+----+------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## STEP 02 : Use `LEFT JOIN` without a `WHERE` clause

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM groupby A LEFT JOIN
    -> (
    ->     SELECT   num, MAX(id) id
    ->     FROM     groupby
    ->     GROUP BY num
    -> ) B USING (id);
+----+------------+------------+
| id | num        | num        |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |  269529129 |       NULL |
|  2 |  387090406 |       NULL |
|  3 | 1126864683 |       NULL |
|  4 |  411160755 |       NULL |
|  5 |   29173595 |       NULL |
|  6 |  266349579 |       NULL |
|  7 | 1244227156 |       NULL |
|  8 |    6231766 |       NULL |
|  9 |  269529129 |  269529129 |
| 10 |  387090406 |  387090406 |
| 11 | 1126864683 | 1126864683 |
| 12 |  411160755 |  411160755 |
| 13 |   29173595 |   29173595 |
| 14 |  266349579 |  266349579 |
| 15 | 1244227156 | 1244227156 |
| 16 |    6231766 |    6231766 |
+----+------------+------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## STEP 03 : Use `LEFT JOIN` with a `WHERE` clause

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM groupby A LEFT JOIN
    -> (
    ->     SELECT   num, MAX(id) id
    ->     FROM     groupby
    ->     GROUP BY num
    -> ) B USING (id) WHERE B.num IS NOT NULL;
+----+------------+------------+
| id | num        | num        |
+----+------------+------------+
| 16 |    6231766 |    6231766 |
| 13 |   29173595 |   29173595 |
| 14 |  266349579 |  266349579 |
|  9 |  269529129 |  269529129 |
| 10 |  387090406 |  387090406 |
| 12 |  411160755 |  411160755 |
| 11 | 1126864683 | 1126864683 |
| 15 | 1244227156 | 1244227156 |
+----+------------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## ANALYSIS

Looking at the aforementioned results, here are two questions:

- Why does a `LEFT JOIN` keep an ordering by `id` ?
- Why in the world did using a `WHERE` impose a reordering ?

  - Was it during the JOIN phase ?
  - Did the Query Optimizer look ahead at the ordering of the subquery or ignore it ?

No one foresaw any of these effects because the behavior of explicit clauses was relied upon by the implicit behavior of the Query Optimizer.

## CONCLUSION

From my perspective, corner cases can only be of an external nature. In light of this, developers must be willing to fully evaluate the results of a `GROUP BY` in conjunction with the following twelve(12) aspects:

1. aggregate functions
2. subquery usage
3. `JOINs` clauses
4. `WHERE` clauses
5. sort order of results with no explicit `ORDER BY` clause
6. query results using older GA releases of MySQL
7. query results using newer beta releases of MySQL
8. the current [**SQL_MODE setting**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode) in `my.cnf`
9. the operating system the code was compiled for
10. possibly the size of [join_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size) with respect to its effect on the Query Optimizer
11. possibly the size of [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) with respect to its effect on the Query Optimizer
12. possibly the storage engine being used (MyISAM vs InnoDB)

Here is the key thing to remember : Any instance of MySQL that works for your query in a specific environment is itself a corner case. Once you change one or more of the twelve(12) evaluation aspects, the corner case is due to break, especially given the first nine(9) aspects.

Comment: Rolando: Thank you once again for providing such a detailed answer, which does indeed show unexpected sort behaviour in a related query.  However, I'm very much struggling to see how this answers the specific question that was being posed.  Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: The direction I chose to answer this question was to not to show any types of reliance on undocumented behavior but to show how reliance on such behavior is often taken for granted and how results are too quickly trusted as genuine.

Comment: The fact that there is a local `GROUP BY` phenomenon and that there is a URL dedicated to it ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html ) shows that corner cases should come as no surprise. Notice how this `GROUP BY` quirk is conveniently called a `MySQL Extension`. Imagine if Oracle now took MySQL and fixed that `GROUP BY` quirk. Imagine if the `SQL_MODE` was defaulted to a strict mode for the GROUP BY : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by . The possibilities for corner cases can just go on...

Comment: I completely agree that "*corner cases should come as no surprise*", but I am struggling to identify a single such example that demonstrates failure of the specific query given in the question.  That is really what I was after, so I'm afraid whilst your answer is definitely worthy of an upvote I really can't award the bounty to its current incarnation.

Comment: My answer just provided an example of two external operations: 1) imposing a `WHERE` clause and 2) using different type `JOIN`. The effects were immediately seen when the results were screened. In a high-volume production environment, any change, however slight the change may be, can reorder data against a developer's will. Corner cases cannot be documented because of the unpredictability of the `GROUP BY`'s behavior. A bug fix that did not make it to release notes. A default setting changing on a new minor upgrade. These can make code change behavior as well.

Comment: Agreed.  And it is specific examples of precisely those things that I am after.  :)

Comment: Another example: I had a MySQL client that uses MySQL 5.1.22 in production (They installed it, not me). MySQL 5.1.30 is the first MySQL 5.1 GA release. They are stuck with the quirk of that beta release. An upgrade would easy reveal many corner cases.

Comment: Another example: If you are a real historian on MySQL, you know that the next community release after MySQL 5.0.37 was MySQL 5.0.41. Any one with MySQL Enterprise subscriptions had Carte Blanche on finding a corner case, contacting MySQL, getting it fixed in a matter of days, and getting MySQL 5.0.38 release to MySQL Enterprise subscribers only. Corner cases are more shielded now with Oracle is controlling the release schedule. With MySQL 5.5, we should find far less internal corner cases. This is why my answer discusses the concept (and empirical example) of external corner cases.

Comment: You just said the key phrase : `current incarnation`. Notice in my conclusion that I named seven things that would reveal a corner case on `GROUP BY`. If one simply sets the SQL_MODE in my.cnf and restarts mysql, my conclusion would have a different list altogether. In fact, I just thought of two more things to evaluate a GROUP BY with. I'll add it to my answer.