# Optimizing a query with ORDER BY in a derived table

Tags: mysql

The query below takes too long to execute (58 seconds). If I run two more queries like this with different `nid` values, the second and third query take much more time to execute. How can I optimize it?

```
SELECT consoleId,
       servertime,
       servertime AS servertimeUNIX,
       nocName,
       eventIdx,
       nocStatus  AS status,
       nid,
       site,
       machine,
       clientversion,
       timeExecuted,
       count(*)   AS eventCount
FROM   (SELECT consoleId,
               servertime,
               nocName,
               eventIdx,
               nocStatus,
               nid,
               site,
               machine,
               clientversion,
               timeExecuted
        FROM   temptest
        ORDER  BY tid DESC) AS x
WHERE  servertime >= 1367902800
       AND servertime <= 1370581199
       AND nid = 1124
GROUP  BY FROM_UNIXTIME(servertime, '%Y-%m-%d'),
          site,
          machine,
          nid;
```

The table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE `temptest`
  (
     `tid`                INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `eventIdx`           INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `servertime`         INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `nocName`            VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
     `site`               VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
     `machine`            VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL,
     `clientversion`      VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `nid`                INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `nocStatus`          VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL,
     `consoleId`          INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `timeExecuted`       VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
     `machineManufacture` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`tid`),
     KEY `consoleindex` (`consoleId`),
     KEY `nitification` (`servertime`, `nid`)
  )
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=8229683
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Why the derived table? Have you tried writing the query without?

Comment: What you are doing (ORDER BY in a derived table, then GROUP BY in the external query), you shouldn't be doing. See **[GROUP BY trick has been optimized away](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/)**

Comment: And a relevant question here, at DBA.SE: **[What corner cases exist when relying on undocumented behaviour to determine values selected by MySQL for hidden columns in GROUP BY operations?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28913/what-corner-cases-exist-when-relying-on-undocumented-behaviour-to-determine-valu)**

Comment: Because I need the records in descending from all the columns.

Comment: Why not include `tid` in the outer query, then you can put the `ORDER BY` where it belongs?

Comment: That derived table is useless. Also, its order by has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT consoleId,
       servertime,
       servertime AS servertimeUNIX,
       nocName,
       eventIdx,
       nocStatus  AS status,
       nid,
       site,
       machine,
       clientversion,
       timeExecuted,
       count(*)   AS eventCount
FROM   temptest
WHERE  servertime >= 1367902800
       AND servertime <= 1370581199
       AND nid = 1124
GROUP  BY FROM_UNIXTIME(servertime, '%Y-%m-%d'),
          site,
          machine,
          nid;
```

Comment: That usage of  `GROUP BY` is incorrect and only "works" because MySQL chooses to return random data in that case. Any other DBMS will righfully reject it. More details here http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html and here http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/  (and you are missing an `ORDER BY`...)

Comment: but op tagged mysql

Comment: Yes and MySQL will simply return random data - and most probably not the one that is expected.. Read the links I posted.

Comment: Just becasue you can do something, doesn't mean you should. It is a poor practice to do group bys this way in ALL databases even if you think you can.